# Error creating notifier on Apigee for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a push notifier for my app. I follow the instructions and was able to get my API key (Android apps) by following the steps in the Registering with a notification service. On Apigee admin panel I named my notifier and supplied my API key. I keep getting an error message. I have searched to see how to resolve.

Comment: Can you add an error message you get?

Comment: all I see is error creating notifier. No other messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

After a while I decided to **remove** the **IP** provided from Apigee in the Google Developers Console (APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Public API access -> Edit allowed IPs)

After that I could just add the notifier in the Apigee Control Panel as described in the docs.

The IP in the docs is probably outdated but I could not find any other.